# Como ordenar registros por el que MAS VECES SE REPITE

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente consulta, todo funciona "Bien":

```
    $consulta = "SELECT DISTINCT IDJuego,Titulo,TipoDeArchivo,Icono FROM solicitar_nes
                 UNION SELECT ID,Titulo,Icono,solicitarRetoque FROM solicitar_pc

 ORDER BY Titulo  DESC limit 7";

$filas = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);
    $registros = [];
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($filas)) {

        $registros[] = $r;
}
```

Y los datos los muestro así;

```
 <?php
    include('consultaSolicitarRetoque.php');
    foreach ($registros as $i) {
        echo "<div class='mb-2'>";
        echo "<a href='/zona_dis_nes/descargas/descarganes.php?id=$i[IDJuego]&tipo=$i[TipoDeArchivo]' class='d-block '><img src='$i[Icono]' width='15' height='15'> $i[Titulo]</a>";

        /*Consulto TOTAL de VOTOS */
        $consulta_votos = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_VOTOSNES FROM solicitar_nes WHERE IDJuego= '$i[IDJuego]' AND TipoDeArchivo= '$i[TipoDeArchivo]' ";
        $totalvotos = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta_votos);
        $arrayvotos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($totalvotos);
        /* ---*/

        echo "<div class='  ml-3  d-inline-block'>$arrayvotos[TOTAL_VOTOSNES] Solicitudes </div>";
        echo     "</div>";
    }
    ?>
```

Me muestra una tabla pero tengo el problema de que siempre se muestran los mismos primeros **7 registros** (Así como se ve en el codigo que estan **"ORDENADOS por Titulo Descendiendo con LIMITE de 7"**

Sin embargo lo que yo necesito es lo siguiente;

**Que se ordene según el registro que mas SOLICITUDES TIENE**

Aquí anexo una imagen del resultado que ya tengo (Pero que no restringe eso que necesito):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar tengo **2 registros de prueba de momento...** Pero cuando pase de los 7 siempre se van a mostrar los mismos y sin el **Orden de prioridad por SOLICITUD** que mencione...

¿Alguna idea de como **CONSULTAR** para que el registro con mas **SOLICITUDES** siempre este hasta arriba con un limite de 7 registros mostrados en pantalla como MAXIMO ?

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Prueba indicandole en que tabla debe ordenar, por ejemplo **ORDER BY solicitar_pc.Titulo  DESC limit 7**

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que construir dos consultas, una agrupada y la otra no, y enlazarlas, de forma que una sirva de ordenación a la otra. Algo así (por cierto, he agregado algún campo porque las dos partes del UNION deben tener los mismos campos. Revisa porque no sé si son tipo numérico o de texto. El Tipo lo he puesto para que no haga un Distinct, ya que el UNION solo trae registros no duplicados. Al añadirle un campo que distingue entre NES y PC ya no se te repiten.

```
SELECT TOP 7
    Q1.IDJuego,
    Q1.Titulo,
    Q1.TipoDeArchivo,
    Q1.Icono,
    Q1.AS SolicitarRetoque,
    Q2.RecuentoTotal

FROM    (
        SELECT 
            IDJuego,
            Titulo,
            TipoDeArchivo,
            Icono,
            '' AS SolicitarRetoque,
        FROM solicitar_nes
        UNION 
        SELECT 
            ID AS IDjuego,
            Titulo,
            '' AS TipoDeArchivo,
            Icono,
            SolicitarRetoque
        FROM solicitar_pc
        ) Q1
    
    INNER JOIN 

    (SELECT  
    IDJuego, 
    Titulo, 
    SUM(Recuento) AS RecuentoTotal
    FROM    (
            SELECT 
                IDJuego,
                Titulo,
                'NES' AS Tipo,
                Count(*) AS Recuento
            FROM solicitar_nes
            GROUP BY IDJuego, Titulo, Tipo

            UNION 
        
            SELECT 
                ID AS IDjuego,
                Titulo,
                'PC' AS Tipo,
                Count(*) AS Recuento
            FROM solicitar_pc
            GROUP BY IDJuego, Titulo, Tipo
            ) Qx
    GROUP BY IDJuego, Titulo
    ) Q2 ON Q2.IDJuego = Q1.IDJuego AND Q2.Titulo = Q1.Titulo 

ORDER BY Q2.RecuentoTotal DESC, Q1.Titulo
```